# PreAuthorize issue on common spring NoRepositoryBean base interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to write a generic SecurePagingAndSorting repository which will check security on CRUD operations to save repeating the same PreAuthorize (with different authorities) throughout all JPA repositories.

Here is a simple example below:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SecuredPagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>     extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {

@Override
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, domainType, 'delete')) 
 void delete(ID id);

}
```

Now it's the domainType argument that's the problem here, since this is a generic interface, it can't be hard coded.  What is the best approach here to get the domain type from repositories that derive from SecurePagingRepository.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I see is writing your own implementation of the interface `PermissionEvaluator` and then inject it in the security context replacing the default one.

Should you try this way, extending class `AclPermissionEvaluator` will save you lots of code already managed by Spring, and ensures back compatibility.

Comment: I was looking at Spring Security ACL, but I still don't see how the hasPermission generic query above can populate the domainType read for when AclPermissionEvauluator needs to do it's thing.  It seems I still would need to pollute each repository implementation with a hasPermission(#id, 'org.company.MyDomainObject',delete) in the scenario above

Comment: I can see there is ongoing work with generic query augmentation, but it seems like it's not quite there yet.

Comment: @CCob for example, you could use a custom value (in the superclass) for the domain type, then perform custom logics in the `hasPermission` method in this case. Otherwise call `super.hasPermission(...)` to ensure back compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I settled on this solution in the end.  PreAuthorize has the facility to use any bean within the Spel expression using the @ character.

```
@Override
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, @security.getDeletePermission(#id,#this.this))) 
void delete(ID id);    
}
```

So when the 'security' bean's getDeletePermission function is called, the #this.this parameter translates to the SimpleJpaRepository in question.  This allows us determine the concrete repository in question and returned the desired permission name